# select multiple columns from multiple tables except certain columns

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

The first table is like:

```
+----+----+----+
| id |  x |  y |
+----+----+----+
```

The second and third tables are like:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| id | Z1 | Z2 | Z3 | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | .. | Zn |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

`n` is quite large, about 800-900.

I know it is quite ugly tables and database. But it is a raw data set and a learning set of a certain experiment. Please, just ignore it.

And a skeleton of a query is like:

```
    'SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* \
    FROM `test_xy` a,  `test_1` b, `test_2` c \
    WHERE a.id = b.id AND b.id = c.id'
```

What I concern is, the result with the query includes `id` field three times. I want  `id` field to appear just one time at the front of the result.

I can do it by slicing the result table (by Python, MATLAB, etc.)

But, is there a better way to do this with a large number of columns? I mean, can `id` field of the second and third tables be excluded at the query stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the USING syntax: MySQL specific by the way. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html. Learn to use JOINs before you do anything else; putting the jon condition into the where clause is just plan wrong.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM `test_xy` a JOIN  `test_1` b USING(`id) 
JOIN `test_2` c USING(`id)
```